# concurrent priority queue using message passing?

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, mpi, priority-queue, message-passing

Is there any concurrent algorithms that implement a priority queue using message passing? The functionality of priority queue is naturally sequential, in order to enable it across multiple processors, one has to take care of the entity locks during insert/delete operations. That said, the insert/delete queries are coming from different processors, and they are feed to the same priority queue. To my knowledge, a classical algorithm to do this is using Skip_list [1], which requires shared memory in the hindsight.

However, I am particularly interested to see if there are any message passing solutions to concurrent priority queue.

[1]  Pugh, W. (1990). "Skip lists: A probabilistic alternative to balanced trees". Communications of the ACM 33 (6): 668. doi:10.1145/78973.78977
ftp://ftp.cs.umd.edu/pub/skipLists/skiplists.pdf

Comment: You might call [flat combining](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~hendlerd/papers/flat-combining.pdf) a form of message passing. A stretch might be an [eliminating priority queue](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1021v1.pdf). [SprayList](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/209108/SprayList_full.pdf) may also be of interest as a relaxed skip list.

Comment: @BenManes Thanks for your suggestion!